# Highly unstable WLAN / Roaming does not work with Debian 8

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian, wireless-roaming

When using mobile devices in large buildings WLAN connection fails forever or longer periods of time when roaming from one access points to another occurs. The WLAN link is always up but no network traffic is possible anymore.

> Drive Used: **iwlwifi**
>
> Hardware: **Intel 7620**

Because this system is a mobile robot we wanted to avoid solutions that require a GUI

The following configurations have been tested and did not work:

**Plain Linux Network Configuration with wpa_supplicant**

Using

> /etc/network/interfaces

and

> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

files to configure the network. Even with wpa-roam and a lot of testing roaming from one access point to another does not work.

**WICD**

Using wicd also failed with roaming. It worked a tiny little bit better and at least managed to reconnect after 5-10 minutes(!). But still not usable

**Updating iwlwifi firmware**

Updating iwlwifi to version 25.228.9.0 did not improve anything.

**Setting iwlwifi module parameters in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf**

In internal tests setting

> options iwlwifi swcrypt=1

Increased throughput from 16 Mbits/s to 80 Mbits/s but did not improve roaming or reliability.

The following settings were tested and had no effect:

> bt_coex_active=0 
>   power_save=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We installed **network-manager** and now the WLAN with roaming in a large building works flawlessly.

Note that we are still using the upgraded iwlwifi firware from the question and the mentionent iwlwifi parameters. We did not test if it also works without these.

**As a conclusion it seems that in big enterprise networks with roaming network-manager is the only working solution.**